# How to get the end date excluding the weekends

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get the **end date**. When **start date** is a date & time and no of days is given as **hours**. I tried using this formula:

```
=WORKDAY(INT(G20),INT(H20/24))+(MOD(G20,1)+MOD(H20/24,1))
```

Does anyone know I am doing it in right way or not? Or if there is better workaround ?

[image]

Comment: I think your algorhithm is fine. Note that your `INT` functions are unnecessary since `WORKDAY` function will truncate any non-integer date values.

Comment: Your screenshot seems to show the correct result. As does the equivalent `=WORKDAY(G20,H20/24)+(MOD(G20,1)+MOD(H20/24,1))`  What makes you think it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now that your formula will have a problem because the adjustment for the hours can theoretically land you on a weekend.

You can "brute force" the results.

Assuming you have Microsoft 365, since you did not specify otherwise in your tags, you can use:

```
=LET(x,WORKDAY(G20,H20/24)+(MOD(G20,1)+MOD(H20/24,1)),x+IFS(WEEKDAY(x,3)=6,1,WEEKDAY(x,3)=5,2, WEEKDAY(x,3)<5,0))
```